# How to delete one number off call list for iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone

What app would I need to download and what are the steps to deleting one number at a time My iphone 3GS is already jailbroken.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the Phone > Recents listing the solution doesn't require a jailbroken phone. In the upper right corner is an `Edit` button. It will allow for the individual deletion of calls from this call log.

If this is not what you're after please provide some more detail for the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

there is no edit button by default..you need to install add-on like cydia. probably newer versions of OS have this edit button added, but i am not sure..